# Excel =Power function, fractional power issue

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to understand why Excel behaves differently when using these two functions:

```
=POWER(-2;1/3)  -> -1.25922

=POWER(-2;0.3333)  -> #NUM!
```

Although 1/3 is much more accurate, why can't Excel Power function handle the less accurate power of 0.3333?

Answer (score 2):

It is a mathematical problem: the cube root of -2 has a real answer (plus two complex answers), but the approximation to a cube root is always a complex number.

If you use `IMPOWER()` instead of `POWER()` you will see the difference:-

```
=IMPOWER(-2;1/3)
=IMPOWER(-2;0.3333)
```